# NotificationService Extension returns different locale than App target

Tags: ios, nslocale, unnotificationserviceextension

I'm trying to get my current locale in the app and in the NotificationService extension. The code looks like this:

`let locale = Locale.current.identifier`

In the app target the locale is `de_DE` and in the NotificationService extension it evaluates to `en_DE` which results in an unwanted behaviour. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to set locale in NotificationService extension as well. Could you please verify the locale set in NotificationService extension?

Comment: @Developer where can I do that? Isn't the locale dependent on the system settings?

Comment: Check in edit schema